# How to get the primary key of new entity added to JPA relationship before tx commit?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Lets say I have a JPA entities that look like the following, full annotations details omitted for simplicity

```
@Entity
public class Order {
   @Id Integer id; 

   @OneToMany List<Parts> parts;          
}

@Entity
public class Part {
   @Id Integer id; 

   @ManyToOne Order order;
}
```

Lets say that I am adding a new part to an existing order

```
Order order = entityManager.find(Order.class,1);
Part newPart  = new Part();
newPart.setOrder(order);
order.getParts().add(part);
// set other part fields

Integer newPartId = newPart.getId();  // newPartId is null
```

Is there a way to get the id of the newly added item without explicitly calling `persist()` on the entity manager or waiting till after the current tx commits?

Comment: I think the last part of the question is very ambiguous: from your title I understand that your problem is getting the PK before transaction commit, but from your question, is calling `persist()` ?OR? waiting for the TX commit. What do you mean by OR?

Answer (score 2):

Once you've fixed your mapping as explained by Andrei's answer, persist your entity and then call `flush()` on the EntityManager, and then get the ID from the entity.

Hibernate won't generate an ID for a non-persistent entity it doesn't even know about.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you have there a bidirectional relationship, in which you do not specify which is the owner of the relationship:

For example, in order to mark the `Part` entity as the owner of the relationship, you add in the `Order` entity the following:

```
@Entity
public class Order {
   @Id Integer id; 

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="parts") List<Parts> parts;          
}
```

And now to your question: it is not possible, as long your entity does not reach the DB. In order to force a synchronization to DB, you must call `entityManager.flush()`. On the other side, you could also call `entityManager.merge()` instead of `persist()`, and after that a flush().

Comment: I omitted the details of the mappedBy ... etc to keep the example simple but those all correctly setup. having mappedBy does not actually help as the id is not assigned at that point.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. The `id` is generated when the entity is persisted for the first time in the database. There's nothing you can do about it.